# remove character in series with replace

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace, series

I have a series that looks like following:

```
datum

02-jun-18

01-jun-18

01-jun-18

30-maj-18

30-maj-18

29-maj-18

27-maj-18

25-maj-18

25-maj-18

25-maj-18

14-maj-18
```

I want to remove the days on each row but keep the month and year with the follwing code:

```
df['datum']=df['datum'].replace(df['datum'][0:2],' ')
```

But it does not work. Can anyone explain why and how I can tackle this problem?

Comment: Post your series *as text*, not as an image.

Comment: @chrisz I have edited my text,is this better?

Answer (score 1):

`df['datum'].replace(df['datum'][0:2],' ')` will replace the first two *rows* with whitespace, not the first two letters in each row.  You want to work with `df.datum.str`

***Option 1*** (If all your months are three letter abbreviations)
**`string slicing`**

```
df.datum.str[-8:]

0    jun 2018
1    jun 2018
2    maj 2018
Name: datum, dtype: object
```

***Option 2***
**`str.replace`** with **`.*\s(\w+\s\w+)$`**

```
df.datum.str.replace(r'.*\s(\w+\s\w+)$', r'\1')

0    jun 2018
1    jun 2018
2    maj 2018
Name: datum, dtype: object
```

Comment: First part of question: "Can anyone explain why...". I'm curious too.

Comment: HIs attempt replaces the first two *rows* with `' '`.  He probably meant `df.datum.str.replace`, but either way that wouldn't work because of the variable number of digits in days, also you can't hash series.

Comment: @chrisz thanks for the answers. One question, what is the method .*\s(\w+\s\w+)$ called in option 2?

Comment: Called regular expression matching.

Comment: @chrisz ok thanks for the answer again. I tried also another approach to solve my problem. Option 3 would be df['datum']=df['datum'].replace(df['datum'][0][0:2],' ') 
I don't know if this is a correct way but it works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `str.split`

```
pd.Series(['18 may 2018','10 jun 2018']).str.split(' ',1).str[1]
Out[209]: 
0    may 2018
1    jun 2018
dtype: object
```